# Accessing field: different value if its stored in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, scope

My problem looks something like this.

```
# Module.py
class TestClass:
    name = "default"
    nameDict = {'name':"standard"}

    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.nameDict['name'] = name
```

Then I call on the fields from another module. The class is initiated before and I call on the name field like this:

```
Module.TestClass("newName")

# Inside another function
print(Module.TestClass.name)
print(Module.TestClass.nameDict['name'])
```

Which gives:

```
default #name
newName #nameDict
```

I don't understand why it would be different values. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question; there's a lot going on.

`Module.TestClass` is the class you've defined in 'Module.py'. With `Module.TestClass("newName")`, you're creating an *instance* of that class, but you're *not* saving it.

When you do `print(Module.TestClass.name)`, you're printing the value of the `name` attribute of `Module.TestClass`, which is the *class*, **not** an *instance* of the class. The `name` you gave the *instance* before doesn't change the *class*' `name` attribute.

The really interesting bit is `print(Module.TestClass.nameDict['name'])`. Even though you're still accessing the `nameDict` attribute of the *class*, it *is* affected by the *instance* you created earlier. This is because Python variables hold references to objects. When you defined the class, you assigned a dictionary to the attribute `nameDict` in the class scope. That *exact same* dictionary object is being pointed at by the *class* **and all** the *instances* of the class. So, if you change it in one place, it's changed everywhere, because it's actually the *exact same dict*.

Here's a good way to do what it looks like you're trying to do:

```
# Module.py

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name='default'):
        self.name = name
        self.nameDict = {'name': name}

# other.py

testclass_instance = Module.TestClass("newName")

# Inside another function
print(testclass_instance.name)  # newName
print(testclass_instance.nameDict['name'])  # newName
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!
 I thought I should call it with an instance but was trying to not, for how I wrote the code. I'll rewrite it!

Comment: Glad I could help :). In that case, could you accept so that the question will be marked as answered?

Answer (score 2):

The difference you are seeing is because -

1. Strings are immutable , whereas dictionaries are mutable .
2. In your init function , when you do - self.name = name - this creates assigns a new reference to name in your instance , that does not change the reference that the class variable name holds .
3. In your init function , when you change the value for the name key in the dictionary , you are mutating the dictionary (which is the same dictionary for the class variable) , hence it reflects in the class variable dictionary as well. If you had assigned a new dictionary here , you would be able to see the old value in the class variable still.

This basically happens because when you create an instance , the class variables' reference are copied as such to the instance, the reference still pointing to whatever class variable pointed to at that time. Since in this case, as the reference is same the changes to dict reflect in the class variable.

But when you do assignment, you are making the variable point to a new reference, and this does not cause the class variable to change.

A simple example to show this -

```
>>> class CA:
...     d = [1,2]
...
>>> CA.d
[1, 2]
>>> c = CA()
>>> c.d
[1, 2]
>>> id(c.d) == id(CA.d)
True
>>> c.d.append(3)
>>> CA.d
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c.d = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> CA.d
[1, 2, 3]
>>> CA.d = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> CA.d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> d = CA()
>>> d.d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c.d
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Didn't know about the copying of class variables to instances. This was the crucial missing point for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour was surprising to me as well:

```
import Module

# Inside another function
print(Module.TestClass.name)             #<-- default
print(Module.TestClass.nameDict['name']) #<-- standard

foo = Module.TestClass("newName")

print(Module.TestClass.name)             #<-- default
print(Module.TestClass.nameDict['name']) #<-- newName
```

Why do you ask for class variables? Maybe you wanted to do:

```
foo = Module.TestClass("newName")

print(foo.name)
print(foo.nameDict['name'])
```

Comment: The class and the instances all share the same dict. That's why just creating an instance changes the class' dict; they are in fact the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Python provides a whole bunch of such pitfalls. It is more like a love-hate to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `TestClass.name` is a string object, therefore immutable, while `TestClass.nameDict` is a mutable dictionary object. So when you are doing `self.name = name`, a new name variable is created on instance with 'newName' value, while when you do `self.nameDict['name'] = name`, the dict class variable is mutated.

To verify this behavior, you can check id of the variables:

Example:-

```
class TestClass(object):

    ...

    def __init__(self, newName):
        print(id(self.name)) #1
        self.name = newName
        print(id(self.name)) #2

        print(id(self.nameDict)) #3
        self.nameDict['name'] = newName
        print(id(self.nameDict)) #4
```

## 1 would be different than #2, while #3 and #4 would be same.

For further reference:- [Mutable and immutable objects in python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)